# Problem with "make & make install" software on linux

Tags: 64-bit, makefile, compilation, configure

I have worked on Linux for a year. One thing bothers me is that I am not familar with the process of installing new software with source code(I can't install them from netword due to environment limitations).

I was often blocked with different kinds of error, for example:

```
------------------------
libtool: install: error: relink `Magick++/lib/libMagick++.la' with the above command before installing it
------------------------
```

or

```
------------------------
magick/.libs/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `gzseek64'
magick/.libs/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `gztell64'
------------------------
```

Though I finally found solution with google, I don't know exactly why it works.

Can anyone helps me with this situation or give me some advice on how to improve myself on such kind of things?

I am lack of the knowledage of "configure","make","difference of 64bit","shared lib"; Could anyone point me in the right direction and give me some helpful books or articles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tips on compiling things(which you are not programming on) usually belong on super-user

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex subject, and the only advice I can think of is to learn it from the bottom up, and stop when you feel you have enough. First learn to **compile** code, in whatever language you like. Once you understand that you can move on to **linking** things, and **building and using libraries**. When you're comfortable with that idea you can experiment with **make**. If that doesn't scare you off, you can then learn how to **configure**.

It's a complicated process, and it's kind of amazing that we don't haven't tamed it better by now.

Comment: Really thanks for your advice:) I have experience with Java applications which always have libraries in the same directory. However, when come to perl, things become complicated, because many shared libraries are used and I can not figure out the dependance. Could you recommend some books or articles on those topic to me?

Comment: I don't know much about Java or compiling Perl, but I've found a lot of good comp-sci information just by doing Google searches. You could try "perl shared libraries" for starters.

Comment: Thanks, Beta. I will try that way~~

Comment: For Perl you should always use the CPAN shell to install CPAN modules: ity will take care of the dependencies for you.  Things get hairier when they depend on libraries that must already be present on your system.